# TFS issue while check in and get latest from server

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I'm trying to get latest and check in files from TFS but tfs return same message

[image]

> Unexpected end of file. Following elements are not closed:
>   PendingChange, PendingChanges, PendingSet,
>   QueryPendingSetsWithLocalWorkspacesResult,
>   QueryPendingSetsWithLocalWorkspacesResponse, Body, Envelope. Line 1,
>   position 881.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this kind of issue may related to cache. Suggest you first **excluded** the pending changes in VS (also backup local changes), then [clear both VS and TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsalm/2013/12/17/how-to-clear-the-tfs-cache-on-client-machines/). Finally include the pending changes and check in again.

If above solution not work, the issue still exists, you could delete local workspace (backup local changes), create a new workspace, then get the latest version from server, add the changes to files, finally check in pending changes.